# Google charts - Get the equation of Linear trendlines

Tags: php, html, charts, google-visualization, jsapi

I have a chart like this (drawn by google charts)
the line is generated by google with option of Linear trendlines

**image**
[image]

**code**

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Diameter', 'Age'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: 'none',
    trendlines: { 0: {} }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

---

how to know the equation of this line?

Comment: Given that you have all the points you can calculate it yourself using this equations https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html

Answer (score 1):

adding the trendline to the legend will reveal the equation...

```
trendlines: {
  0: {
    visibleInLegend: true
  }
}
```

you can remove the series from the legend, if so desired...

```
series: {
  0: {
    visibleInLegend: false
  }
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Diameter', 'Age'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

once the equation has been added to the legend,
you can get the value from the `<text>` element used to draw the legend marker
but need to wait on the `'ready'` event first,
to know the chart has finished drawing

also, you will need a way to determine the legend marker `<text>` element
from the other labels, such as the chart title
in this example, both the title and the legend marker
have an attribute `text-anchor` with a value of `'start'`

`text-anchor` could change depending the legend's `alignment` and `position`

the font color (`fill`) is used to separate the title from the legend marker...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Diameter', 'Age'],
    [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age of sugar maples vs. trunk diameter, in inches',
    hAxis: {title: 'Diameter'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Age'},
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    },
    trendlines: {
      0: {
        visibleInLegend: true
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var equation = $('text[text-anchor="start"][fill="#222222"]').text();
    console.log(equation);
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know hiow to extract this equation from the legend and put it into variable like this: $variable = "y=4.885-x+0.73" or  $variable = 4.885*x+0.73

Comment: Note that if there are many data series, the legend part can get crowded and the legend could be truncated with the ellipsis (...). In that case the full formula can be only extracted from the tooltip of the legend. This is really hacky.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  console.log(chart.Zl().jp[1].text);
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

chart.Zl().jp looks like this:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "",
    "text": "Age",
    "brush": "{\"fill\":\"#3366cc\",\"fillOpacity\":1,\"stroke\":\"none\",\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeOpacity\":1,\"strokeDashStyle\":\"solid\",\"rx\":null,\"ry\":null,\"gradient\":null,\"pattern\":null,\"shadow\":null}",
    "index": 0,
    "ja": false
  },
  {
    "id": "_trendline",
    "text": "y = 4.885 * x + 0.73",
    "brush": "{\"fill\":\"#3366cc\",\"fillOpacity\":0.5,\"stroke\":\"none\",\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeOpacity\":1,\"strokeDashStyle\":\"solid\",\"rx\":null,\"ry\":null,\"gradient\":null,\"pattern\":null,\"shadow\":null}",
    "index": 1,
    "ja": true
  }
]
```

so for each series there will be two objects, one for series and second for trendline, so if for example you have two trendlines you can get the second equation with `chart.Zl().jp[3].text`

Comment: It seems that chart.Zl().jp[1].text no longer works. Maybe google have rebuild the library. Please note that if this code is in production you may want to check it out. I have yet to find an alternate solution.

Comment: Additional information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/SaQnVkXTUO8

Comment: To continue using the code above you should use
window.google.charts.load("45.2", { packages: ["corechart"] });